# A closet contains 10 pairs of shoes. What is the probability of getting exactly one pair if two left and two right shoes are chosen?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

### Question:

> A closet contains 10 pairs of shoes. What is the probability of getting a pair if two left and two right shoes are chosen?

I did it this way but I'm not sure if it's correct:

number of ways to select two left and two right shoes $=(10C2)\times(10C2) =45\times45 =2025$

number of ways to select a matching pair =N(select 1 pair from 10 and select both left and right, then select 2 pairs from remaining 9 and select 1 of right or left from each of pair)

$=(10C1)\times(2C2)\times(9C2)\times2 =10*1*36*2 =720$

therefore probability= $720/2025 =16/45$

Comment: Is it exactly one pair or at least one pair?

Comment: Exactly one pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that given that you have 2 left shoes.

The chance that the first right shoe chosen does not pair with one of the two you have is $\frac {8}{10}$ and the second not pairing is $\frac{7}{9}$

No pair is $\frac {56}{90}.$
Pairing up at least once must be $\frac {34}{90} = \frac {17}{45}$

Comment: But I need the probability of getting exactly one pair, not at least one

Comment: You don't say exactly 1 in your question.  I read it to be at least one the way it is written.  Exactly 1, then we could subtract the possibility we have paired both and get $\frac {16}{45}$

Answer (score 1):

Sure. *If* you seek the probability for obtaining *exactly* one matched pair.

You can simplify your calculations.   You don't care which two from the left shoes you select, only whether the two from the right shoes are their matches or not.

Whatever left shoes you select, there are ${^2C_1}$ ways to select a matching right shoe, and $^8C_1$ ways to select a non-matching right shoe, among the $^{10}C_2$ ways to select right shoes.
$$\dfrac{16}{^{10}C_2}=\dfrac{16}{45}$$

---

You can evaluate the probability for *at least* one matching pair in a similar manner, or consider the probability for *no* matching pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is correct for "exactly one pair"

Using binomial coefficients you have

- number of ways to choose any 2 pairs of left and right shoes: $\color{blue}{\binom{10}{2}\binom{10}{2}}$
- number of ways to choose exactly one pair (e.g., any 2 left ones and then 1 from the not pairing 8 and 1 of the 2 pairing ones): $\color{blue}{\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{1}\binom{2}{1}}$

Hence,

$$P(\text{exactly one pair}) = \frac{\color{blue}{\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{1}\binom{2}{1}}}{\color{blue}{\binom{10}{2}\binom{10}{2}}} = \frac{16}{45}$$